# openejb embedded container cannot find persistence.xml

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, ejb, openejb

I am using openEjb in embedded mode to test a stateless session bean, which has an injected EntityManager. However, when I run the test, it fails because it could not initialize the application. When I see the console I can also see an error related to not being able to find persistence.xml

Note: I tried putting WebContent, as well as META-INF in the classpath, but that does not help either.

**Update:**

There is something very strange about resource lookups when using openejb + eclipse.

1. I added WebContent to source folders. I stopped getting the persistence.xml error, but now I get an error which suggests that openejb could not find any managed resource
2. I added WebContent to source folders, but with a different output folder (using allow output folders for source folders), and the persistence.xml error starts occuring again
3. I copied META-INF into 'test', which is the source folder for all tests, and everything runs fine
4. Regarding points 1, and 2, teh issue seems to be the fact that WEB-INF also gets included as part of WebContent. If I exclude WEB-INF, then again openejb can find persistence.xml in the test and the test runs fine

I am honestly clueless about what is happening.

I am pasting all the relevant errors and code below.

**Error stack from failing JUnit test in Eclipse**

```
org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer$InvalidApplicationException: org.apache.openejb.config.ValidationFailedException: Module failed validation. AppModule(name=)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer$Provider.createEJBContainer(OpenEjbContainer.java:273)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:56)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:43)
    at com.diycomputerscience.slides.service.SlideServiceTest.setUp(SlideServiceTest.java:45)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.config.ValidationFailedException: Module failed validation. AppModule(name=)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.deploy(ReportValidationResults.java:82)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build(AppInfoBuilder.java:264)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:696)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer$Provider.createEJBContainer(OpenEjbContainer.java:267)
    ... 18 more
```

**My console output:**

```
Apache OpenEJB 4.0.0-beta-2    build: 20120115-08:26
http://openejb.apache.org/
INFO - openejb.home = /home/user/workspace/wwald/slides
INFO - openejb.base = /home/user/workspace/wwald/slides
INFO - Using 'javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer=true'
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Default Security Service)
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
INFO - Inspecting classpath for applications: 38 urls. Consider adjusting your exclude/include.  Current settings: openejb.deployments.classpath.exclude='', openejb.deployments.classpath.include='.*'
INFO - Found EjbModule in classpath: /home/user/workspace/wwald/slides/build/classes
INFO - Searched 38 classpath urls in 2000 milliseconds.  Average 52 milliseconds per url.
INFO - Beginning load: /home/user/workspace/wwald/slides/build/classes
INFO - Configuring enterprise application: /home/user/workspace/wwald/slides
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Stateless Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Stateless Container)
INFO - Auto-creating a container for bean SlideService: Container(type=STATELESS, id=Default Stateless Container)
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Managed Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Managed Container)
INFO - Auto-creating a container for bean com.diycomputerscience.slides.service.SlideServiceTest: Container(type=MANAGED, id=Default Managed Container)
INFO - Dumping Generated ejb-jar.xml to: /tmp/ejb-jar-5804778531295096416slides.xml
INFO - Dumping Generated openejb-jar.xml to: /tmp/openejb-jar-2921830618491817127slides.xml
ERROR - FAIL ... SlideService:  Missing required persistence.xml for @PersistenceContext ref "em" to unit "entities"
ERROR - Invalid EjbModule(name=slides, path=/home/user/workspace/wwald/slides/build/classes)
INFO - Set the 'openejb.validation.output.level' system property to VERBOSE for increased validation details.
WARN - configureApplication.loadFailed
```

**The Stateless Session Bean:**

```
@Stateless
public class SlideService {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="entities", type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    private EntityManager em;

    //various business methods not shown for brevity
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="entities">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <jta-data-source>myds</jta-data-source>
        <non-jta-data-source>myds</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**The JUnit test case:**

```
public class SlideServiceTest extends TestCase {

    private SlideService slideService;

    public SlideServiceTest(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        final Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put("myds", "new://Resource?type=DataSource");
        p.put("myds.JdbcDriver", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        p.put("myds.JdbcUrl", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:slidedb");

        EJBContainer ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
        Object oSlideService = ejbContainer.getContext().lookup("java:global/slides/SlideService");
        assertNotNull(oSlideService);
        this.slideService = (SlideService)oSlideService;
    }

    //not showing test methods for brevity, since the code fails in setUp itself
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I received the same exception and the problem was that two `persistence.xml` were on the classpath of OpenEJB.

When I removed one of them, the problem was solved.

The exception message is not helpful here on part of OpenEJB, but if you debug into `org.apache.openejb.config.Appmodule`'s `hasFailures()` or `hasErrors()` method, you can see more useful info in `EjbModule.getValidation()` calls! (Version 4.0.0).

Answer (score 3):

Maven creates directory structure for web projects as shown below:

```
src->main-+->java
          +->resources->META-INF
          +->webapp->WEB-INF
```

To resolve your issue you should create dir [META-INF] under directory [resources] and place persistence.xml there.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that while running junit, JUnit starts to think the WAR file as JAR file hence tries to find the persistance.xml in META-INF at root, while in WAR file the META-INF gets created inside WebContent folder. I simply created a symbolic link in the src folder pointing to the original META-INF. And voilla...............it worked.  :)